# How to make moment.js show relative time in seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time, momentjs

The following script shows the relative time from now to 2017/07/03.

```js
document.write(moment("20170703 00:00:00", "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss").fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It returns something like `in 5 months`, while I expect something like `in 123456789 seconds`.

Answer (score 5):

You can get seconds between two moment objects using [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) specifing `'seconds'` unit as second parameter:

```js
var mom = moment("20170703 00:00:00", "YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss");
document.writeln(mom.fromNow());
document.writeln(mom.diff(moment(), 's'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to customize how moment shows relative time (e.g. the `fromNow()` output)  you can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) and [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/). Here an example:

```js
var mom = moment("20170703 00:00:00", "YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(mom.fromNow());

// Change relativeTimeThreshold
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60*60*24*30*12);

moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    s: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture){
      return number + ' seconds';
    },
  }
});

console.log(mom.fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get the seconds left from now in this way:

```
var seconds = moment("20170703 00:00:00", "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss").unix() - moment().unix()
```