# momentjs seconds until a date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm Using momentjs to find the time until a date.

```
moment(end).locale('nl').fromNow('s')
```

Currently using this, only this this returns `1 day`

I'm looking for something like `86400`

Is this possible with momentjs?

Comment: Possible duplicdate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508796/moment-js-how-to-use-fromnow-to-return-everything-in-hours

Comment: You can also see [How to make moment.js show relative time in seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42216583/4131048)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of October 2018 , you can also do this :

```
  const date = '20181031'
  const time = '16:25:26'

  console.log(moment().diff('2018/10/31 18:14:00')) // time difference  in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it using the following line of code

```
moment().diff(end, "seconds")
```

Note: this will give a negative time